# How Do I Assign Individual Colors to Bars in VB.NET Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I want Individual Color to each Bar in the same-series[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ldfa.gif) like image

i want like image random color in Y value bar

I want Individual Color to each Bar in the same-series

How do I do this in VB.NET Chart?

Any hint or Idea is appreciated

Pls find below Code

```
    Sub LoadChart4()
        With Chart4
            .Series.Clear()
            .Series.Add("Series1")
        End With

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT gt, COUNT(*) as total FROM tblStatus WHERE month(sdate) = month(getdate()) AND year(sdate) = year(getdate()) group by gt", cn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Gt")
        Chart4.DataSource = ds.Tables("Gt")
        Dim series1 As Series = Chart4.Series("Series1")
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar

        series1.Name = "GT"

        With Chart4
            .Series(series1.Name).XValueMember = "Gt"
            .Series(series1.Name).YValueMembers = "total"
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMMM"
            .Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM)



        End With
    End Sub
```

Thanks for advance

Ratheessh

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Chart.palette :

```
With Chart4 
.Palette = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.Bright
etc...
```

note from Microsoft :
A palette is used to automatically assign colors to data elements if both of the following conditions have been met:

the data points themselves do not have colors assigned to them.

the data series that the data points belong to also does not have an assigned color.

have a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.palette?view=netframework-4.8.1